# Daily Notification even after cancel does not cancel it for next day

Tags: android, checkbox, notifications, alarmmanager

I have created repeating daily notification. Everything works fine but when my checkbox is unchecked it cancel the alarm for that day and fire the notification next day for the same time.
 What i want is to cancel alarm if my checkbox is unchecked until i will checked it again.

In my Setting Activity class, i have set the time on clicking the checkbox and  called cancelAlarm method when the checkbox  is unchecked.Here is the method :

```
public void onClick_dailyClassNotification(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox_settingClassNotification:
            if (checked) {
               // ((CheckBox) view).setChecked(false);    //initially 
    checkbox wont be checked
                showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
            }
            else
            {
                check = false;
                sharedPreferenceManager.setPreferences
           (SettingActivity.this,"check",String.valueOf(check));
                Notification_service.cancelAlarm(context);
                 Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Notification 
      Cancelled" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
    }
 }
```

This is cancelAlarm Method

```
 public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
      /*if(alarmManager != null)
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);*/
        Intent i = new Intent(context, Notification_Receiver.class);

         pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast
    (context,100,i,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         alarmManager=(AlarmManager) 
       context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
```

Please Help.

Comment: You should single out, which code is getting called when the checkbox is unchecked.  Doing so would help people trying to answer your question.

Comment: cancelAlarm method in my Notification_receiver class.

Comment: I mean, you should single that out in your post-- to help people reading what you wrote understand what you're asking-- instead of just scrolling through a whole bunch of code to try to figure out what's wrong.  Also, it's harder to read what you answered, when it's not aligned and in the comments.

Comment: I am facing this problem..and i am not able to complete my project.Please Help. @Alex